# Backup all data from AWS account to local file system

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have pretty uncommon task - backup all data and configurations from AWS account to local storage (and then potentially restore them). 
OR at least EC2 snapshots and then restore them

Comment: regarding the EC2 snapshots - https://serverfault.com/questions/763523/copying-an-ebs-snapshot-to-s3-for-low-cost-storage

Comment: thank you, it is definitely not easy solution, but is better than nothing.